# Reusing AJAX function multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, reusability

Currently my AJAX call is set up as such so that when a comma keyup is detected, the AJAX call fires:

```
$("#selector").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 188) {

        var search = $(this).val();

        function searchTag() {
            return $.ajax({
                cache:      false,
                url:        url,
                dataType:   "json",
                type:       "post",
                data:       {search: search}
            });             
        }

        searchTag().done(function(data) {
            //Success
        });
    }
});
```

I want to reuse the AJAX call as part of another event listener later in my code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".tag", function () {
    searchTag();
});
```

Without rewriting the entire call, how do I make the function independent so that it can be used in both scenarios?

Comment: Then why don't you move function searchTag outside the `keyup` event (and make the search var a global and apply the value on keyup only) ?

Comment: @drip I'd like to avoid global variables if I can.

Comment: Then wrap the code in self invoking anonymous function...

Comment: Or you could declare that variable in $(document).ready() scope where I believe you have placed your events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the function outside:

```
function searchTag(data) {
    var url = "yoururl";
    return $.ajax({
        cache:      false,
        url:        url,
        dataType:   "json",
        type:       "post",
        data:       data
    });             
}

$("#selector").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 188) {

        var search = {search: $(this).val()};


        searchTag(search).done(function(data) {
            //Success
        });
    }
});

$("body").on("click", ".tag", function () {
    searchTag({});
});
```

Comment: Also faced the same  issue, this works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

remove the function from the event, and add as input the search value and url as input:

```
function searchTag(searchVal, url) {
            return $.ajax({
                cache:      false,
                url:        url,
                dataType:   "json",
                type:       "post",
                data:       {search: searchVal}
            });             
        }

$("body").on("click", ".tag", function () {
    var searchVal = $(this).val();
    var url = document.URL; //use any url here
    searchTag(searchVal, url);
});
```

you could even use a callback:

```
function searchTag(searchVal, url, callbck) {
            return $.ajax({
                cache:      false,
                url:        url,
                dataType:   "json",
                type:       "post",
                data:       {search: searchVal}
            }).done(function(){
              callbck();
            });             
        }

$("body").on("click", ".tag", function () {
    var searchVal = $(this).val();
    var url = document.URL; //use any url here
    searchTag(searchVal, url, function(){
        //do something here..
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
///tag -> tag to search
///cb  -> callback to executed on success
var searchTag = function(tag, cb) {
    var url = "http://example.com";
    var request = $.ajax({
        cache:      false,
        url:        url,
        dataType:   "json",
        type:       "post",
        data:       {search: tag}
    });          
    request.done(cb);
}

$("#selector").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 188) { 
        var search = $(this).val();
        searchTag(search, function(data) {
            //Success
        });
    }
});

$("body").on("click", ".tag", function () {
     //I don't actually know where the tag to search is stored
     var search = $(this).html();
     searchTag(search);
});
```